# Close Outlook Add In From Inside Application

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook Office Add-in built using Angular which is utilizing the `Office.js` library. The purpose of the add-in is to perform a one-time action for the message currently being displayed. Once the submit button is clicked for the action in the add-in, there is no need to have the add-in open anymore.

Is there a way to close the add-in frame altogether from inside the application? For instance, something like `Office.close();`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using the [`UI.closeContainer` method](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.closecontainer?product=outlook):

```
Office.context.ui.closeContainer();
```